# Given two points in 2D space A,C , find a third point C with fixed distances to A,B

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

Given two points in 2D space, say $A=(x_1,y_1$), $B=(x_2,y_2)$, find a third point $C=(a,b)$ that it's distances to A and B will be d1 and d2.
This problem seems quite easy to solve, since it can be described as 2 equations with 2 variables:
$$(y_1-b)^2 + (x_1-a)^2 = d_1^2$$
 $$(y_2-b)^2+(x_2-a)^2=d_2^2$$
but the solution for this two equations is quite cumbersome. 
I tried to go directly at it and the beginning is ok: by subtracting the equations we get:
$$ b=\frac{(y_1^2-y_2^2)+(x_1^2-x_ 2^2)-2(x_1-x_2)a-(d_2^2-d_1^2)}{2(y_1-y_2)}$$ When I place the result in any of the original equations it gets pretty messy.
 I also tried to think of the dots as vectors, or with polar coordinates, but I didn't get any further.

Can anyone think of a little bit more elegant solution?

Comment: Do you want the solution as an expression in the variables $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, $y_2$, $a$, $b$? If so, I think it's going to be quite cumbersome, no matter how you derive it.

Comment: I want to find a formula for (a,b) , given A=(x1,y1), B=(x2,y2) and distances d1,d2. thanks anyway

Comment: If $\lvert \overline{AB} \rvert \gt d_1 + d_2$, there are no solutions. If $\lvert \overline{AB} \rvert = d_1 + d_2$, there is one solution (on the line between points $A$ and $B$, distance $d_1$ from $A$, and distance $d_2$ from B). In the rest of the cases, $\lvert \overline{AB} \rvert \lt d_1 + d_2$, and there are two solutions, mirrored by the line $AB$. There is a formula, but it is several lines long. Even as a pseudocode function, using temporary variables to simplify it, it has over 50 multiplications, four divisions, one square root, and over 50 additions or subtractions.

Comment: On the other hand, if you rotate, translate, and scale (uniformly) the problem so that $A$ is at $(0,0)$, $B$ is at $(1,0)$, distances $d_A = d_1/\lvert\overline{AB}\rvert$ and $d_B = d_2/\lvert\overline{AB}\rvert$, and look for the points $(w,\pm h)$, $0 \le w \le 1$, $h \ge 0$, it does become much simpler. Can you find the solution for this simpler $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$, $d_A + d_B \ge 1$ case? It is surprisingly easy to extend to the general case, you see.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the point using vectors.

If there is a solution to the problem (if and only if $d1+d2>= |AB|) then ABC is a triangle, which we know the size of all of its edges, and there for we can find its angles. Then we can find point C threw vector operations.
for example:

let say we have :  $A = (1,0)$, $B = (6,6), d_1=1$ $, d_2=7$ and we are looking for point C.

First let's think of AB as a vector: $\vec{AB}=(\sqrt{61},50.1944^\circ)$.

Then we can compute $\angle B=33.67^\circ =\theta $ (by cosine rule or any other way). Now we know point C is at the end of a vector $\vec{BC}$ that its length is $d_1=1$ and it's direction is $33.67^\circ$ **relatively**  to the opposite direction of $\vec{AB}:$  $$50.194- 180 + \theta =  -96.136$$ Then find point C using vector addition from point B:
$$ C_x = 6+d_1*cos(-96.136) \approx5.89312$$
$$ C_y = 6+d_1*sin(-96.136) \approx 5.0057$$

For the second solution we can do the same computation for : 
 $50.194- 180 - \theta$...